# Computing the average of $\prod_i (1-\frac{|x_i|}{L})$ on the surface of the unit $n$-sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, spheres, surface-integrals

I'm trying to compute the expected value of $ \prod_i (1-\frac{|x_i|}{L})$ on the surface of a $n$-dimensional sphere. A first step could be to integrate only on the first quadrant to take out the absolute value (since the function is symmetric).

The intuition behind it (if I'm not wrong) is that for $L>1$  that product is the probability that, if we put edge-parallel planes in every dimension separated by distance $L$, a point in the surface of the unit sphere will end up in the same hypercube as the origin.

For 2 dimensions it's easy because we can pass to polar coordinates:

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} (1-\frac{\cos \theta}{L})(1-\frac{\sin \theta}{L}) = 1- \frac{4L-1}{\pi L^2}$$

What about higher dimensions?

Comment: Did you try looking at $\prod_i \left(1-\frac{\mid x\mid}{L} \right)$ as $\sum_i \log\left(1-\frac{\mid x\mid}{L} \right)$?

Comment: And, on the surface of the n-hypersphere, one could say that $\mid x\mid = r$, no?

Comment: No I didn't, but the expectation over the log cannot be directly linked to the original expectation because the log is non-linear transform, right?

Comment: No, it's |x_i|, not |x|. |x_i| is the absolute value of the i-th coordinate, which can be any value from 0 to 1 in the surface of the unit sphere.